# How to access my external JSON file in javascript in order to create it as HTML?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have a little script I am trying to write. As the user scrolls to the end of the page, new content is loaded into the browser. I'm using fetch() to grab the JSON file. I am able to see exactly what I want throughout the script through console.logs and or alerts but for some reason when in the appendMissionSection function, all that's appending to the page is a bunch of undefined. I'm

```js
function fetchData () {
  'use strict'
  // FETCH API AND GETS A PROMISE
  window.fetch('https://jennp1987.github.io/dynamicContent/js/indexAbout.json')
  // GETS RESPONSE AND CONVERTS INTO JSON
    .then(response => {
      // window.console.log(response)
    // IF RESPONSE NOT OKAY, THROW ERROR
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error('ERROR')
      }
      // WAIT FOR RESPONSE.MUST COVERT INTO SOMETHING YOU CAN USE. JSON RETURNS PROMISE.
      return response.json()
    })
  // ONCE YOU HAVE JSON CREATE SECTION
    .then(data => {
      // window.console.log(data.mission)
      // window.alert(data.mission)
      appendMissionSection(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      window.console.log(error)
    })
}
//APPEND NEW HTML IN BROWSER
function appendMissionSection (data) {
  window.console.log(data)
  // var myMission = JSON.parse(data)
  // window.console.log(myMission)
  var body = document.querySelector('body')
  for (var info in data) {
    var aboutSection = document.createElement('section')
    aboutSection.innerHTML = info.data
    body.appendChild(aboutSection)
    window.console.log(body)
  }
}

function yHandler () {
  'use strict'
  var wrap = document.querySelector('body')
  // GET PG CONTENT HEIGHT OF EVERYTHING WITHIN DIV
  var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight
  // GET VERTICAL SCROLL POSITION - GTS WHERE USER IS IN THE Y POSITION
  var yOffset = window.pageYOffset
  // TARGETING THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE
  var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight

  // IF USER HAS GONE TO THE BOTTOM OR OVER
  if (y >= contentHeight) {
    fetchData()
  }
}
window.onscroll = yHandler
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


body {
 font-family: BrandonGrotesque, sans-serif !important;
/* perspective-origin: 0% 50%;*/
/* perspective: 800px;*/
 background-color: #21212d !important;
 border-top: 1em #3f4756 solid;
 /*
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
*/
}
/*PRELOADING BCKG IMG*/
/*
body::after{
 position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
 content: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewpng825.png');
}
*/

/*MAIN*/
main{
transition: transform 150ms ease-out;
/* position: absolute;*/
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: auto;
/* padding: 1em 4em;*/
 max-width: 100%;
 background-color: #3f4756;
 transform: none;
}
main.menu-active {
 transform: translateX(1em) rotateY(1deg);
}

/*NAV*/
nav {
 font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Medium, sans-serif;
/* z-index: 100;*/
}

.navbar > button {
 background-color: #353441;
 color: white;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 letter-spacing: .1em;
 border-radius: 0;
/* z-index: 300;*/
}

.navbar > button:hover {
 color: #353441 !important;
 background: white !important;

}

/*
.navbar > button > div > ul > li > a{
 margin-left: 1em;
 
 
}
*/
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
 padding-left: 1em !important;
}

.navbar li {
 list-style: none;
 padding-right: .5em;


}

#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div {
 background-color: #353441;
}

.navbar li,
collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown > div {
 background-color: #353441;

}

/*STYLES A*/
#collapseExample > ul > li > a,
#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div > div:nth-child(1) > a,
#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div > div:nth-child(2) > a {
 color: #9dc6d1;

}

/*HOVER STYLE*/
.navbar li a:hover {
 background-color: #a4844e;

}
.navbar-toggler:focus,
 li .dropdown a:active, #collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > a{
 outline: none;
}

/*STYLE THE INNER Of DROPDOWN*/
#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div {
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}
/*NAV COLS*/
body > div > div{
/* z-index: 400;*/
}

/*END NAV*/

/*MAIN*/

/*
main{
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;

}
*/

/*END MAIN*/
/*
.jumbotron::after{
 position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
 content: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewpng825.png');
}
*/
/*HEADER*/
#jumbotron {
 max-width: 100%;
 background: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewpng825.png');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 1100px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #21212d;
 border-radius: 0 !important;

}

div .headerContainer {
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 padding: 0 0 0 150px;

}

/*
h1,h2,h3{
 display: inline-block;
}
*/
h1 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 101px;
 width: 70%;
 height: auto;
 color: #a4844e;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;

}

h2 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 70px;
 width: 70%;
 height: auto;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-style: normal;
}

h3 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 55px;
 color: #a4844e;
 width: 70%;
 height: auto;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
}

.headerContainer h1 {
 font-size: 101px;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #a4844e;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: #21212d;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
 transform: translate(0%, 80%);
}

.headerContainer h2 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-style: normal;
 transform: translate(8%, 90%);

/*
 animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
 -webkit-animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
 -ms-animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
 -moz-animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
*/


/*
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
*/
 
 animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -o-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;


}


/*
@-webkit-keyframes move {

 0% {
  transform: translate(50%, 170%);
 }

 100% {
  transform: translate(8%, 170%);
 }

}
*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}



.headerContainer h3 {
 font-size: 55px;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
 transform: translate(30%, 100%);
}
/*EX EX LG SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1582px) and (min-width: 1552px){
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 125px;
 }
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1551px) and (min-width: 1433px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 125px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1{
  font-size: 70px !important;
 }
 .headerContainer h2{
  font-size: 55px;
  
 }
 .headerContainer h3{
  font-size: 38px;
 }
 
}
/*EX LG SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1432px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 110px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 68px !important;
 }

 h1 {
  font-size: 68px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 50px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 35px !important;
 }


}


/*LG SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 105px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 55px !important;
 }

 h1 {
  font-size: 55px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 40px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 30px !important;
 }

}

/*LG SCREEN TO MEDIUM*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1119px) and (min-width: 768px) {
/*
 .navbar-collapse{
  padding-right: .5em !important;
 }
*/
}

/*MED SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 48px;
 }
/*
 main.menu-active{
  transform: none;
 }
*/
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 45px !important;
 }


 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 32px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 25px !important;
 }

}

/*ALL SCREENS SMALLER THAN 767*/
@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-12.navDiv {
  position: absolute !important;

 }
 main.menu-active{
  transform: none;
 }

 header .jumbotron {
  position: relative;

 }
 body > div > div > div.col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-12 > nav {
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
 .navDiv {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  


 }
 

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-sm-12 {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;

 }
 .jumbotron {
 max-width: 100%;
 background: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewMobile.png');

 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #21212d;


}

 



}

/*SM SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 577px) {

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-12 > nav {
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
 .navbar-toggler {
      padding: .25rem 1.2rem !important;
  
 }
 button {
  /* width: 100%;*/
  text-align: left;
 }
 .navDiv {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
 }
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 100px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 43px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 35px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 25px !important;
 }

}

/*EX SM SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) and (min-width: 363px) {

 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 2em 0 0 100px;
 }

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-sm-12 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 28px !important;
 }

 h1 {
  font-size: 28px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 12px !important;
 }
 

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 362px){
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 2em 0 0 20px;
 }
 h1 {
  font-size: 28px !important;
/*  transform: translate(0%, 80%);*/
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
/*  transform: translate(8%, 90%);*/
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 12px !important;
/*  transform: translate(30%, 100%);*/
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Scroll for Dynamic Content With Ajax</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/ufy4eie.css">


 <style type="text/css">
 
  div#wrap {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;

  }


  div.newData {
   height: 1000px;
   background: #09F;
   margin: 10px 0px;
  }

 </style>

</head>

<body>
  <header id="jumbotron">
   <div class="headerContainer">
    <h1>FRONT END</h1>
    <h2 class="fade-in">WEB DEVELOPER</h2>
    <h3>web &amp; graphic designer</h3>
   </div>
  </header>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

not sure if I am writing my for in loop the right way or if it's because I need to use JSON.parse(data). I've tried to mess around with both possibilities but I'm stuck.

Comment: `response.json()` returns a promise of the results of `JSON.parse`, so don't parse it again. What do you see in your `window.console.log(data)` at the top of `appendMissionSection`? You may want to change that to `window.console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` so it's easy to read.

Comment: This is what I see when I change to the code above...{
  "mission": "Dedicated to delivering creative assets that have a positive user experience, aesthetically pleasing layouts, and engaging functionality that provide enjoyable digital experiences.",
  "link": "Read Story Here."
}

Comment: So that means you have `data.mission` and `data.link`, both of which are just strings. Nothing to loop over. So it sounds like you just need to remove the loop, keeping the new `section` and set the `innerHTML` to `data.mission`. Not sure what you want to do about `link`.

Comment: Yes! that worked! Thank you so much. I'm still learning when to use loops.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function fetchData () {
  'use strict'
  // FETCH API AND GETS A PROMISE
  window.fetch('https://jennp1987.github.io/dynamicContent/js/indexAbout.json')
  // GETS RESPONSE AND CONVERTS INTO JSON
    .then(response => {
      // window.console.log(response)
    // IF RESPONSE NOT OKAY, THROW ERROR
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error('ERROR')
      }
      // WAIT FOR RESPONSE.MUST COVERT INTO SOMETHING YOU CAN USE. JSON RETURNS PROMISE.
      return response.json()
    })
  // ONCE YOU HAVE JSON CREATE SECTION
    .then(data => {
      // window.console.log(data.mission)
      // window.alert(data.mission)
      appendMissionSection(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      window.console.log(error)
    })
}
//APPEND NEW HTML IN BROWSER
function appendMissionSection (data) {
  window.console.log(data)
  var body = document.querySelector('body')
    var aboutSection = document.createElement('section')
    aboutSection.innerHTML = data.mission
    body.appendChild(aboutSection)
    var button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerHTML = data.link
    body.appendChild(button)
}

function yHandler () {
  'use strict'
  var wrap = document.querySelector('body')
  // GET PG CONTENT HEIGHT OF EVERYTHING WITHIN DIV
  var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight
  // GET VERTICAL SCROLL POSITION - GTS WHERE USER IS IN THE Y POSITION
  var yOffset = window.pageYOffset
  // TARGETING THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE
  var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight

  // IF USER HAS GONE TO THE BOTTOM OR OVER
  if (y >= contentHeight) {
    fetchData()
  }
}
window.onscroll = yHandler
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


body {
 font-family: BrandonGrotesque, sans-serif !important;
/* perspective-origin: 0% 50%;*/
/* perspective: 800px;*/
 background-color: #21212d !important;
 border-top: 1em #3f4756 solid;
 /*
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
*/
}
/*PRELOADING BCKG IMG*/
/*
body::after{
 position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
 content: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewpng825.png');
}
*/

/*MAIN*/
main{
transition: transform 150ms ease-out;
/* position: absolute;*/
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: auto;
/* padding: 1em 4em;*/
 max-width: 100%;
 background-color: #3f4756;
 transform: none;
}
main.menu-active {
 transform: translateX(1em) rotateY(1deg);
}

/*NAV*/
nav {
 font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Medium, sans-serif;
/* z-index: 100;*/
}

.navbar > button {
 background-color: #353441;
 color: white;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 letter-spacing: .1em;
 border-radius: 0;
/* z-index: 300;*/
}

.navbar > button:hover {
 color: #353441 !important;
 background: white !important;

}

/*
.navbar > button > div > ul > li > a{
 margin-left: 1em;
 
 
}
*/
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
 padding-left: 1em !important;
}

.navbar li {
 list-style: none;
 padding-right: .5em;


}

#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div {
 background-color: #353441;
}

.navbar li,
collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown > div {
 background-color: #353441;

}

/*STYLES A*/
#collapseExample > ul > li > a,
#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div > div:nth-child(1) > a,
#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div > div:nth-child(2) > a {
 color: #9dc6d1;

}

/*HOVER STYLE*/
.navbar li a:hover {
 background-color: #a4844e;

}
.navbar-toggler:focus,
 li .dropdown a:active, #collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > a{
 outline: none;
}

/*STYLE THE INNER Of DROPDOWN*/
#collapseExample > ul > li.nav-item.dropdown.show > div {
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}
/*NAV COLS*/
body > div > div{
/* z-index: 400;*/
}

/*END NAV*/

/*MAIN*/

/*
main{
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;

}
*/

/*END MAIN*/
/*
.jumbotron::after{
 position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
 content: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewpng825.png');
}
*/
/*HEADER*/
#jumbotron {
 max-width: 100%;
 background: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewpng825.png');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 1100px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #21212d;
 border-radius: 0 !important;

}

div .headerContainer {
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 padding: 0 0 0 150px;

}

/*
h1,h2,h3{
 display: inline-block;
}
*/
h1 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 101px;
 width: 70%;
 height: auto;
 color: #a4844e;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;

}

h2 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 70px;
 width: 70%;
 height: auto;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-style: normal;
}

h3 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 55px;
 color: #a4844e;
 width: 70%;
 height: auto;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
}

.headerContainer h1 {
 font-size: 101px;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #a4844e;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: #21212d;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
 transform: translate(0%, 80%);
}

.headerContainer h2 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-style: normal;
 transform: translate(8%, 90%);

/*
 animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
 -webkit-animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
 -ms-animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
 -moz-animation: move 3s ease-in-out 1s normal;
*/


/*
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
*/
 
 animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -o-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;
 -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 8s;


}


/*
@-webkit-keyframes move {

 0% {
  transform: translate(50%, 170%);
 }

 100% {
  transform: translate(8%, 170%);
 }

}
*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}



.headerContainer h3 {
 font-size: 55px;
 font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
 transform: translate(30%, 100%);
}
/*EX EX LG SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1582px) and (min-width: 1552px){
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 125px;
 }
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1551px) and (min-width: 1433px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 125px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1{
  font-size: 70px !important;
 }
 .headerContainer h2{
  font-size: 55px;
  
 }
 .headerContainer h3{
  font-size: 38px;
 }
 
}
/*EX LG SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1432px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 110px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 68px !important;
 }

 h1 {
  font-size: 68px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 50px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 35px !important;
 }


}


/*LG SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 105px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 55px !important;
 }

 h1 {
  font-size: 55px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 40px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 30px !important;
 }

}

/*LG SCREEN TO MEDIUM*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1119px) and (min-width: 768px) {
/*
 .navbar-collapse{
  padding-right: .5em !important;
 }
*/
}

/*MED SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 48px;
 }
/*
 main.menu-active{
  transform: none;
 }
*/
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 45px !important;
 }


 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 32px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 25px !important;
 }

}

/*ALL SCREENS SMALLER THAN 767*/
@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-12.navDiv {
  position: absolute !important;

 }
 main.menu-active{
  transform: none;
 }

 header .jumbotron {
  position: relative;

 }
 body > div > div > div.col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-12 > nav {
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
 .navDiv {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  


 }
 

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-sm-12 {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;

 }
 .jumbotron {
 max-width: 100%;
 background: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/Creative-Cog-Design/images/creativeCogHeaderNewMobile.png');

 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #21212d;


}

 



}

/*SM SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 577px) {

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-12 > nav {
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
 .navbar-toggler {
      padding: .25rem 1.2rem !important;
  
 }
 button {
  /* width: 100%;*/
  text-align: left;
 }
 .navDiv {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
 }
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 0 0 0 100px;
 }
 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 43px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 35px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 25px !important;
 }

}

/*EX SM SCREEN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) and (min-width: 363px) {

 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 2em 0 0 100px;
 }

 body > div > div > div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-sm-12 .headerContainer h1 {
  font-size: 28px !important;
 }

 h1 {
  font-size: 28px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 12px !important;
 }
 

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 362px){
 div .headerContainer{
  padding: 2em 0 0 20px;
 }
 h1 {
  font-size: 28px !important;
/*  transform: translate(0%, 80%);*/
 }

 .headerContainer h2 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
/*  transform: translate(8%, 90%);*/
 }

 .headerContainer h3 {
  font-size: 12px !important;
/*  transform: translate(30%, 100%);*/
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Scroll for Dynamic Content With Ajax</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/ufy4eie.css">


 <style type="text/css">
 
  div#wrap {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;

  }


  div.newData {
   height: 1000px;
   background: #09F;
   margin: 10px 0px;
  }

 </style>

</head>

<body>
  <header id="jumbotron">
   <div class="headerContainer">
    <h1>FRONT END</h1>
    <h2 class="fade-in">WEB DEVELOPER</h2>
    <h3>web &amp; graphic designer</h3>
   </div>
  </header>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed your adding section part to target correct values. Hope this works for you.